# PythonAnywhere trying to upload my website

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, beautifulsoup, pythonanywhere

I am trying to upload my web-app on PythonAnywhere, but I am not able to do that.I have tried many ways and also searched on google but I am unable to solve it. Please tell me what I am lacking in or what more information should I add here. I have also added the Error Log from PythonAnywhere. Please someone explain me the error also if possible as what I am doing wrong.

my file structure

```
|-mysite/
    flask_app.py
    |-templates/
        index.html
```

`run.py`

```
from flask import render_template
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element
import urllib2
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
  def index():
  i=1
  count =1
  items = []
  heads = []
  bodys = []
  writers = []
  dates=[]
  m = 0
  while(i<21):
      url = 'http://www.goal.com/en-gb/rumours/last/168?page='+str(i)+'&ICID=OP'
      response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
      html = response.read()
      soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
      i +=1

      # Collect rumors posts
      rumour_post_tags = soup.find_all("div", {"id":"rumours"})


      for rumour_tags in rumour_post_tags:
          content_tags = rumour_tags.find_all("div",{"class":"rumour-content"})
          for rumour in content_tags:
             items.append(count)
             count +=1
             heads.append(rumour.find("h3",{'class':'column'}).text)
             bodys.append(rumour.find('p').text)
             for sources in rumour.find_all('span',{'class':'column'}):
                 for source in sources:
                     if m % 2 == 0:
                         writers.append(source)
                         m += 1
                     else:
                         dates.append(source)
                         m += 1
  return render_template('index.html',allitems=zip(items,heads,bodys,writers,dates))
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Goal's Transfer Talks</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Transfer Talks</h2>
    {% for item,head,body,writer,date in allitems %}
    <h3>{{ item }}. {{ head }}</h3>
    <p>{{ body }}</p>
    <footer>
    <p>{{ writer }}</p>
    <p>{{ date }}</p>
    </footer><br>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting an error when I am trying to open my website through `http://rahul3103.pythonanywhere.com/` which is:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Error Log:

```
2015-07-29 11:17:57,179 :Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/rahul3103/mysite/flask_app.py", line 19, in index
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

WSGI Configuration file:

```
# This file contains the WSGI configuration required to serve up your
# web application at http://<your-username>.pythonanywhere.com/
# It works by setting the variable 'application' to a WSGI handler of some
# description.
#
# The below has been auto-generated for your Flask project

import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = u'/home/rahul3103/mysite'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path

# import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work
from flask_app import app as application
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [open url from pythonanywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597390/open-url-from-pythonanywhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have a free account and PythonAnywhere only allows access to the internet for a [whitelist of sites](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/).

Comment: Is there any other way, i can do that

Comment: Yeah goal.com is not there and my website is live on heroku. Thanks for the help.  [My website](https://footballs.herokuapp.com/)